# GetOpenFileName Focus

Tags: c, winapi, openfiledialog, win32gui

I have two simple programs written in C running at the same time. The first program has a GUI window, while the second program has no window (hidden).

The first program (GUI) sends a TCP command to the second program (hidden), and the second program opens a file dialogue using Win32 API `GetOpenFileNameA()`. The issue is this file dialogue box shows behind the GUI window.

**Question:**

**How do I run `GetOpenFileNameA()` and force focus on it?**

```
OPENFILENAMEA ofn;
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
ofn.lpstrFile = FILE_PATH;
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(FILE_PATH);
ofn.lpstrFilter = "All Files\0*.*\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

if (GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn)) {
    return FILE_PATH;
}
```

Comment: If you specify a hook procedure (lpfnHook), that procedure will receive the WM_INITDIALOG message, and from there you should be able to tamper with the focus. Another thing that may be worth trying is to set hwndOwner to be the HWND of the first program (the non-invisible one), since window handles can be shared between processes.

Comment: Thank you @SvenNilsson, for your comment. In my case, just adding `ofn.lpfnHook` was enough.

Comment: @AlbertShown Filtering on `WM_INITDIALOG` may still be a good idea though. It may be overkill to bring it to top for every message that goes to the dialog box :-)

Comment: Why is a GUI app asking a non-GUI app to display a GUI in the first place? Sounds like a backwards design to me. IMHO, the GUI app should display the dialog and then send the filename to the non-GUI app for processing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, your accepted solution works fine on all Windows except for Windows 11 for some reason. I will try `WM_INITDIALOG` to see if it makes it work on Windows 11.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Yes, that will be the best way to do it, but unfortunately, we don't control the GUI program in our project, that's why.

Comment: @AlbertShown the correct way to prevent the dialog from going behind the GUI is to set the GUI window as the owner of the dialog

Comment: First program calls AllowSetForegroundWindow to give permission to the second program to steal focus from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably force it on top by providing a callback function for messages intended for the dialog box:

```c
UINT_PTR OFNHookProcOldStyle(HWND hdlg, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    BringWindowToTop(hdlg); // or SetWindowPos 
    return 0;
}
```

Then set

```c
ofn.lpfnHook = OFNHookProcOldStyle;
```

before calling `GetOpenFileNameA`.

Note: This does not change the foreground window or force focus on your dialog box, but may be enough to bring it out of hiding so it appears on top of the GUI window.

---

In Windows 11 it the flag `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` must be specified for the hook procedure to be called. It was probably a requirement before W11 too, but it seemed to work anyway. Setting that flag alone makes it show an old-style dialog though - but adding the `OFN_EXPLORER` flag and defining the hook function as below seems to work:

```c
UINT_PTR Lpofnhookproc(HWND hdlgChild, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (uiMsg == WM_INITDIALOG) {
        BringWindowToTop(GetParent(hdlgChild)); // I think GetParent is needed
    }
    return 0;
}

// and then:
ofn.lpfnHook = Lpofnhookproc;
```

This dialog box is however not exactly as the default you'll get without a hook and I can't figure out how to make it so. It is possible to specify a template for the dialog but I wasn't successful in getting the same look as the default.

```c
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ENABLEHOOK;
```

It's maybe possible to fix the look of the dialog box by figuring out what to specify as the `lpTemplateName`:

```c
ofn.lpTemplateName = MAKEINTRESOURCEA( ? ); // unsure about this one
```

and adding `OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE | OFN_ENABLETEMPLATEHANDLE` to the flags.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's that simple. [`BringWindowToTop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-bringwindowtotop) does what the name implies: It brings the window to the top of the Z order. It doesn't. however, make it the foreground window, and input focus doesn't change. See [Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083) for inspiration on addressing that part.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not sure since I can't try it now. I read on `SetWindowsPos`:  _"A window can be made a topmost window either by setting the `hWndInsertAfter` parameter to `HWND_TOPMOST` and ensuring that the `SWP_NOZORDER` flag is not set, or by setting a window's position in the Z order so that it is above any existing topmost windows."_ Apparently there was a _Vista re-architecture_ done, but that was 2 years before Chen's blog entry - and he would certainly know about that :-)

Comment: ... and it also says _"Applications can change an activated window's position in the Z order without restrictions, or it can activate a window and then move it to the top of the topmost or non-topmost windows."_ - but for `SetForegroundWindow` it seems a lot more restrictive. I think my suggestion works because it doesn't `SetForegroundWindow`.

Comment: Indeed. And by consequence, it doesn't change the foreground window. Which the question is asking for (*"force focus on it"*).

Comment: @IInspectable ... ah, yes, you are correct. I need to add a disclaimer. Edit: Disclaimer added.

Comment: After I read your comments, I test it on `Windows 7`, it works, `Windows 10`, it works, `Windows 11`, it does not work.

Comment: @AlbertShown I've just come home to see how this works out for me. Yes, you need to set the flag `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` too (at least on W11) - but that's not enough. It will then open an old-school dialog. Also adding the `OFN_EXPLORER` flag and chaing the callback function to an [`OFNHookProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commdlg/nc-commdlg-lpofnhookproc) makes a newer dialog box appear - but I don't get the same box as without the callback. Annoying. :) Looking into it a bit more ...

Comment: Thank you for your precious help :-) I forgot to say that the first program (hidden) runs the second one using `CreateProcessA`, so I can get some process info to help us make the `GetOpenFileNameA` works better !!

Comment: I didn't mention the info about `CreateProcessA` because the second program is Google Chrome, so the browser window is just a child of the parent process.

Comment: @AlbertShown I've updated it with what I've managed to figure out for now. I hope it makes the dialog box pop up even though it may not look exactly as before :-)